# Как получить процент, на который картинки похожи или отличаются друг от друга через Imagic::compareImages?

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

Вот у меня есть две картинки, отличающиеся на несколько пикселей+потери при сжатии ВК:

[image: картинка]

[image: и картинка]

при выполнении

```
$image1->compareImages($image2, Imagick::METRIC_MEANSQUAREERROR)
```

возвращает массив:

```
Array ( [0] => Imagick Object ( ) [1] => 3.5163383008121E-5 )
```

А можно ли получить процент, на сколько эти картинки похожи/отличаются?

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать определить compareImages для:

1. абсолютно одинаковых изображений;
2. абсолютно разных (например черный и белый квадрат).

А далее через пропорции определять процент схожести.